# Google Drive API QuickStart NODE.JS sample doesn't work

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Using the ***exact example code*** given in the [Google Drive APIs | Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs), the file information that is retrieved is not an accurate representation of the contents of my Google Drive. That is, even though there are 100+ filenames displayed, only one file (a folder) is actually on the 'My Drive' for my account!

Also I have then tried to 'filter' the files selected by using the query string (eg. "q: mimeType='image/jpeg'", and others), but it has no affect; the exact same results are returned.

Here is a truncated sample of the output. The 'Temporary' file is the folder which does exist in my account's "Google Drive 'My Drive'" but the others do not.

```
Files:
Temporary (17xAXYQzw0zYHpjeUP03sdx7qPd1Cnvv0)
Core Odd Years (0BxSZz46t09z1d0t1VWFkTkVkeWs)
Core Even Years (0BxSZz46t09z1ZTVVcm1lWEZvXzA)
Lesson Plans (1AhnLWyjBqtgTa-ofelROlZsnmzX1HiCl)
Hobbies (0BxSZz46t09z1ZkVQbTRiMTB1YTQ)
Hobbies-Steps-Overview.pdf (1E0E15rNOMCHV7OrjMCihjPK2yNLVpIdj)
Heritage (0BxSZz46t09z1cEpiWlYxWm1rNjA)
...
```

I expect that this is a well inspected example, so I'm unsure what could be the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Investigating further, I have found that this problem (ie. 'google.drive('v3').list()' retrieving unknown files) occurs on one of two of the Google accounts that I have access to. Since I'm running the exact same code only with different credentials, I have not been able to determine the difference.  However the 'filtering' using the "q" parameter fails in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for the solution, how about this answer? I think that 2 issues might be included in your situation.

1. About files which are not existing in your Google Drive.

   - The files might be the shared files.
2. In your question, you say that `q` cannot be used.

   - This might be due to the version of googleapis.

In order to confirm above issues, can you try the following 3 points?

1. For `q`, please try to use `q: "'me' in owners"`.

   - This means that the files without sharing are displayed.
   - This is the same to `sharedWithMe = false`. Because `sharedWithMe = false` cannot be used, `q: "'me' in owners"` is used for this situation.
2. For `q`, please try to use `q: "sharedWithMe"`.

   - This means that only the shared files are displayed.
   - Or please confirm "Shared with me" in your Google Drive using your browser.
3. If `q: "'me' in owners"` and `q: "sharedWithMe"` cannot be used for your environment, please confirm the version of googleapis for node.js.

   - If you are using no latest version, please update to the latest one. The current version is [v28.0.1](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/releases).
   - I confirmed that the sample script of quickstart can be used for v27.0.0 - v28.0.1.

#### Reference :

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

If my answer is not useful for you, I'm sorry.